# Is there a standard for translating grades across Erasmus universities?

Tags: grades, student-exchange

I've just finished my Erasmus period in the Netherlands. I'm still waiting for one result from my guest academy, then the Transcript of Record will reach my home university and, somehow, the results will be translated from Netherlands marks to Italian marks.

Is there an Erasmus standard on how to predictably translate results between ranking systems?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECTS_grading_scale ?

Comment: @Enthusiastic This (and another question you just retagged) are about translation in the sense of "mapping one thing to another thing", not "translating from one language to another" as defined in the tag excerpt.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the translation is up to the universities who do the conversion. I think that it is unlikely that there are is one set of guidelines as even within a country not all universities have necessarily the same ranking systems.

I have found [this table](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://www.sowi.rub.de/mam/images/auslandsstudium/umrechnungstabelle_noten.pdf&rct=j&sa=U&ei=lQM8T82XBOnJ0QW7neVs&ved=0CCQQFjAE&q=erasmus+grade+translation&usg=AFQjCNF1ed-eRBTDXIhteYRf-tD1dSnkIw) on Google though that gives some idea on what grades are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Like host Drew Carey used to puts it on his old quiz show:

> "Welcome to Whose Line Is It Anyway?", the show where everything is made up and the [points don't matter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gl__LLKMIs)!

Grades are not consistent, nor consistently translatable, across departments, courses, professors, semesters - all within a single university. So you want to have that across different universities in different countries?